# Scroll-then-fixed header without scroll-linked effects warning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My page has a header that scrolls with the page, then becomes a sticky header when the user scrolls past a certain point.

Here's my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 189) {
        $(".header").addClass("header--is-fixed");
    } else {
        $(".header").removeClass("header--is-fixed");
```

I'd like to use position: sticky; but it's just too new right now.

Here's a page that also has the type of header I'm looking for: https://squareup.com/pos/payments

I include this link because the page doesn't trigger the scroll-linked effects warning, yet it's not using position: sticky;. Just like my code, classes are being toggled on scroll position. I took a look at the js for Square, and it's above what I can do. I'm hoping there's a way to do get this functionality with jQuery without having Firefox give the warning.

Comment: position:fixed; is the thing you are looking for.

Comment: I'm using that. The class "header--is-fixed" adds position: fixed;. Everything I'm my site is working properly, I'm wondering how to not have to use scroll-linked effects, like the Square website.

Comment: They have 2 headers: one is relative and visible at first time, second - fixed and hidden. While scrolling - first hides, second appears.

Comment: Yes, but that's a minor difference, it still involves using js to change css when scrolled to a certain part of the page. The code would be very similar if there's one header or two. My question is how do I have jQuery watch the scroll position without Firefox giving the "this page uses scroll-linked effect"?